Excel formula to qualify groups of matching rows off variables in individual rows
I've got an Excel workbook with ~3 million total line items where I've been asked to find how many transactions (which can be made up of several of these line items and are designated/grouped by a unique transaction ID) have have had at least one line item get denied (status code "D") and where that line item's payment amount is 0.
The part that's stumping me is how to make Excel take the transaction id's into account and give results based on that grouping. For example for something like the following table:



Transaction ID
Line Item ID
Status
Payment Amount




123
1231
A
50


123
1232
A
75


123
1233
A
325


123
1234
D
0


123
1235
D
0


456
4561
A
25


456
4562
A
125


456
4563
A
450


456
4564
A
150


789
7891
D
0


789
7892
D
0


789
7893
D
0


789
7894
A
50


789
7895
A
75


789
7896
A
250



I'm trying to come up with a formula that would be able to determine that there are 2 transactions with denials (123 and 789) and 1 without (456). Ultimately I want to be able to use that to calculate a rate of denied transactions.
I've been using COUNTIFS formulas to generate line item-level totals and that's worked fine so far, but I'm not sure how to add in any logic for grouping or selecting for distinct values on just one column or anything like that. The closest I've been able to find has been 1/COUNTIF to find the total amount of unique values but that isn't quite what I need.

It seems you want to know how to report the number of Transactions that have Status D in your sample data.  Have you considered GROUPBY?

@sealocal - using GROUPBY in Excel 2010 is rather difficult.

Based on your sample I think a pivot table offers the simplest solution

@GerryLopez is the Excel 2010 tag accurate, or are you on a more recent version maybe?

Completely pathetic users don't really have clear information nor they have used older versions of excel. Availability of COUNTIFS() is from Excel 2007 onwards while MS documentation don't show Excel 2010 and Excel 2013 since those versions are declprecated. Therefore people commenting and giving solutions do some research before commenting and giving solutions. Not every users worldwide uses ms365.

@nkalvi The information on the page you linked to is inaccurate (wrong). At the moment, e.g. Excel Functions(Alphabetical) has still the somewhat correct info i.e. if a function has no Excel version attached to it, it is available at least since Excel 2007.

@VBasic2008, thank you very much for kindly pointing it out. I will remove my comment. I'm very happy to learn from long time users like you.

Hey, 1) is the data imported from multiple files in the same folder, possibly with periodic updates? 2) Or is to in multiple workbooks or multiple sheets in one workbook? With 3M rows, it could very slow with calculations with screen update turned on. As others also have mentioned, making use of Power Query is more suitable.

I think the simplest way of doing it in Excel 2010 is to use a couple of helper columns to simplify the formulas and make it easier to filter on data if required.

The Helper column identifies line items defined as "Denied":
=IF(AND(C2="D", D2=0), 1, 0)

The next column identifie each transaction with at least one denied line item based on the previous column:
=IF(SUMIFS($E$2:$E$1000, $A$2:$A$1000, A2) > 0, 1, 0)

And finally the count of denied transactions is calculated using an array formula:
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(F2:F1000=1, MATCH(A2:A1000, A2:A1000, 0)), ROW(A2:A1000)-ROW(A2)+1), 1))


Excel supports just over 1M rows, so I'm assuming your source file is actually a csv exported from a database since it has 3M rows. You will not be able to load so many rows into an Excel workbook. Thus, you need to load the source file through PowerQuery, add it to the Data Model, which supports almost 2B rows, and then use a PivotTable to construct the report. Here's how I would do it:

Excel 2016 and later version have PowerQuery already included, but if you are on Excel 2010 as the tag suggests, download the free PowerQuery add-in from Microsoft (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39379).

Open a new Excel workbook, go the Data tab and click on Get Data > From File > From CSV and select the source file.

On the next dialog click on Transform Data

Once PowerQuery window opens click on Close and Load dropdown and select Close and Load To...

On the next dialog select PivotTable Report and check the box Add this data to the Data Model

Construct the PivotTable similiar to the example below.



You can also use the formulas below in Excel 2021 and newer, however not on 3M rows. I'm including them just for completeness. Formulas for Excel 2010 would have to use CSE (Array) formulas or helper columns like Michal suggested.

Here are both formulas for easier pasting:
Distinct list of Transaction IDs that have Status D and Payment Amount 0:
=UNIQUE(FILTER(tbl[Transaction ID];(tbl[Status]="D")*(tbl[Payment Amount]=0)))

Count of such transaction IDs:
=COUNTIFS(tbl[Transaction ID];G4;tbl[Status];"D";tbl[Payment Amount];0)

If you just want to calculate the rate (share) of these types of transactions this should also be enough:
=COUNTIFS(tbl[Status];"D";tbl[Payment Amount];0)/COUNTA(tbl[Status])


Limiting to functions available in Excel 2010, you could try this. I'd love to know how it performs with the amount of data you have :)
Logic is very similar to Michal's.
Based on the example shown in screenshot (steps are shown using spill arrays, F2#…),

Number of denied transactions:
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF((C2:C16 = "D")*(D2:D16 = 0),A2:A16,""),IF((C2:C16 = "D")*(D2:D16 = 0),A2:A16,"")),1))

Number of transitions without any denials:
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(
IF(((C2:C16 <> "D") + (D2:D16 <> 0)) * ISNA(MATCH(A2:A16, IF((C2:C16 = "D")*(D2:D16 = 0),A2:A16,""),0)),A2:A16,""),
IF(((C2:C16 <> "D") + (D2:D16 <> 0)) * ISNA(MATCH(A2:A16, IF((C2:C16 = "D")*(D2:D16 = 0),A2:A16,""),0)),A2:A16,"")
),1))


PowerQuery
After importing the files or tables, create queries manually or via steps.
Get distinct transaction ids for denied:
let 
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name = "Table1"]}[Content],
  filterRows = Table.SelectRows(Source, each [Status] = "D" and [Payment Amount] = 0),
  keepTxnId = Table.SelectColumns(filterRows, {"Transaction ID"}),
  distinctTxnId = Table.Group(keepTxnId, {"Transaction ID"}, {{"Count", each List.Count(List.Distinct([Transaction ID])), Int64.Type}}) 
 in
    distinctTxnId

Get id without denials, using LeftAnti join with denied ids:
let 
  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name = "Table1"]}[Content],
  filterRows = Table.SelectRows(Source, each [Status] <> "D" or [Payment Amount] <> 0),
  keepTxnId = Table.SelectColumns(filterRows, {"Transaction ID"}),
  distinctTxnId = Table.Group(keepTxnId, {"Transaction ID"}, {{"Count", each List.Count(List.Distinct([Transaction ID])), Int64.Type}}),
  notInDenied = Table.NestedJoin(distinctTxnId, {"Transaction ID"}, DeniedTransactions, {"Transaction ID"}, "DeniedTransactions", JoinKind.LeftAnti) 
 in
    notInDenied

Load data into Excel.

This is easily done using COUNTA, UNIQUE and FILTER.  I formatted your data as a structured table to keep things clean:
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(Table1[Transaction ID],(Table1[Status]="D")*(Table1[Payment Amount]=0))))

This uses the FILTER function to return an array if the Transaction IDs that meet the criteria.  It then uses UNIQUE to consolidate that list into unique Transaction IDs. And then COUNTA to return a count of the unique list.
